# Using capsol.exe in a .net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, caspol

I am creating a .net application which on running from network gives error due to no trust.
So i want to use caspol.exe . i know the command line to use it manually. But how can i use it to make the path trusted for the application itself? How can i implement it in my application so that it becomes trusted.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a security nightmare if applications could grant themselves trust?  Why can't you run caspol.exe during the installation of the app?  Or look into ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Just update to .NET 3.5 SP1, it trusts local networks.  Otherwise caspol is required.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I have already created application in .net platform. So how can i change it to clickonce deployment?